# How can I clone a Spreadsheet with the SheetsAPI for Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am trying to clone a Spreadsheet. How can I do that if I only have the SpreadSheetID? I tried the following and got message: "ALREADY_EXISTS"

```
 Spreadsheet spreadsheet = getService().spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetID).execute().clone()
            .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                    .setTitle(title));
    spreadsheet = getService().spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet)
            .setFields("spreadsheetId")
            .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Instead of the Sheets API, use the Drive API

It features the method [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy).

Java [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy#examples):

```
File copy = new File();
Drive.Files.Copy copyFile = driveService.files().copy(spreadsheetID, copy);
```